# Error message in a property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, properties

This is my problem. If a user type a number in the textbox is all right, but if he type a char, I don't see the messagebox () in the property. 
Why ?

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         TabIndex="12" 
         Text="{Binding Time_HH, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat='{}{##}'}" 
         FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  
         MaxLength ="2" 
         Height="30" 
         Width="30" />
```

And this is the property

```
Private _Time_HH As Integer

Public Property Time_HH() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Time_HH
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        For i = 0 To Len(value.ToString)
            If IsNumeric(value.ToString(i)) = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Error")
                value = 0
            End If
        Next

        _Time_HH = value
        OnPropertyChanged("Time_HH")
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: _value as Integer_ then _value.ToString()_ no way that an integer could contain a char not numeric (a part the sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Time_HH` property is an Integer, there's no way it's gonna contain a non-numeric character.

At most, what will happen is that your Binding will fail due to the type mismatch (is your TextBox showing a red outline?)

If you wanna check if your user enters non-numeric characters, you have to use a type that allows so: a String.

Try this:

```
Private _Time_HH As Integer
Public Property Time_HH() As String
    Get
        Return _Time_HH.ToString()
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        For i = 0 To Len(value)
            If IsNumeric(value.ToString(i)) = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Error")
                value = 0
            End If
        Next

        _Time_HH = Integer.Parse(value)
        OnPropertyChanged("Time_HH")
    End Set
End Property
```

If you need to use the numeric value, use the Integer field. You could create a second property of type Integer that simply exposes the field, if you want to use it for another Binding or something like that (remember to raise the `OnPropertyChanged` for that property too, then, on the `Time_HH` setter)

**CAUTION** - The code above will raise an Exception if the user types something like "00,01-2,0". `IsNumeric` returns `True` for all the characters in that String, but that doesn't mean it is a correct number.

In my opinion, it would be better to do this:

```
Private _Time_HH As Integer
Public Property Time_HH() As String
    Get
        Return _Time_HH.ToString()
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Dim int As Integer

        If Integer.TryParse(value, int) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error")
        End If

        _Time_HH = int
        OnPropertyChanged("Time_HH")
    End Set
End Property
```

Sorry if I did some mistakes, I usually code in C# and my VB is pretty rusty :P